# Save an image from a picturebox as a jpeg file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, helper

I am looking for the easiest way to save an image as a .jpeg file in c#.
Everything that I tried gave me an error GDI+ or something else.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I tried with Image.Save and FileStream.

```
  private void button1_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e) //Saving decoded image as a file        
    {
        Stream Stream;
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog2 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog2.Title = "Save as a text file.";
        saveFileDialog2.Filter = "Image files (*.jpeg;)|*.jpeg;";
        saveFileDialog2.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog2.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (saveFileDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((Stream = saveFileDialog2.OpenFile()) != null)
            {                                   
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(saveFileDialog2.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
                Stream.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: it would be beneficial if you show what you've tried. Otherwise people might also suggest that.

Comment: You are right, I will add the code.

Comment: The stream looks unnecessary since you only care about the file name.  Make sure the file isn't currently locked (did you load the file previously?).  I would fix your dialog title.  Your FilterIndex is outside your range, too.